# How to iterate over an array of objects with jquery templates each command

Tags: jquery-templates

In Javascript I have a `User` object that contains an array of `department` objects like so:

```
user = 
{
   departments: [
        {id: 1, name: 'Department 1'},
        {id: 2, name: 'Department 2'},
        {id: 3, name: 'Department 3'}
   ]
}
```

Using jquery templates (version 1.4.2) I want to render a `<select>` tag like so:

```
<select name="departmentId" id="department">
    {{each departments}}
        <option value="{{= id }}">{{= name }}</option>
    {{/each}}   
</select>
```

This doesn't produce any values in the option elements. How do access the id and name properties of each of the department objects with the template.

Comment: "Doesn't work" is _never_ a sufficient problem description.

Comment: Amended question so it no longer says "doesn't work" but explains that the code doesn't produce values in the option elements

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use it like

```
<select name="departmentId" id="department">
{{each departments}}
    <option value="${idField}">${textField}</option>
{{/each}}</select>
```